# ReferenceError: Cannot access before initialization circular dependency

Tags: javascript, webpack, circular-dependency

In the simple example below im getting the following error :

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'shared' before initialization

but if i change the **export default 2** to a function it will work. Why is this behaviour?

**index.js**

```
import a from "./testA.js";
export default 2;
```

**testA.js**

```
import shared from "./index.js";

console.log(shared);

export default function () {}
```

Comment: Where is `shared` in `index.js`?

Comment: @TechySharnav just a variable name that corresponds to number 2

Comment: @TechySharnav as `index.js` has a `export default`, you can import this default export by any name you want. It's essentially the same as `const shared = require('./index.js').default`

Comment: Are you using `shared` variable anywhere in ` testA.js` (apart from `import`)?

Comment: @TechySharnav No, its just the example above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked this both with webpack (code transpiled to es5) and with native modules in Chrome. With transpiled code it just logs `undefined`.
It only gives an error with native modules no matter if the export is a function or number.

This is because, as the error implies, the `default` export of `index.js` isn't initialized by the time you're trying to `console.log` it.

It's equivalent to doing something like:

```js
console.log(a);
const a = 2;
```

`shared` will be initialized when 2nd line in `index.js` is executed, but the execution of `index.js` stops on line 1 and waits till execution of `testA.js` is done.

When compiled to es5, there's a different problem because the partially completed module is passed to another, so whatever wasn't initialized by that time ends up as `undefined`.

Comment: I dont get the same behaviour as yours. In transpiled code i ge this error as well and when exporting functions works well.

Comment: please post an example of this behavior on https://codesandbox.io/ then.